# Git: Duplicates of files are created

Tags: git, duplicates

I work in a team of 3 developers. Sometimes when people commit files, there is a duplicate also added that has the name in this format :

```
filename.extension~
```

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a temporary file created by your text editor.

For starters, add this to your `.gitignore` file to prevent new such files from being tracked:

```
*~
```

However if these are getting committed, it suggests that you are simply committing all files, perhaps through the use of something like `git add .` or `git add *`.

Instead of doing this, I recommend explicitly adding the files (or chunks) you want to commit. At the very least it is worth doing `git diff --cached` before committing to make sure you know what's being included.

Being deliberate about what you're committing will make your repository's history easier to read.